# TFS- MTM - Unable to successfully configure the test controller to communicate with TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, mstest, mtm

I am trying to set up a system where I can run selenium automated test from MTM.

The issue I am facing is I am not able to configure Test Controller successfully. I believe this is due to some permission issue. Below is the set up I am using

[image]

The error I am getting while clicking on Apply Settings is below

```
E, 2016/08/22, 16:20:19.541, Failed to obtain the service account from the hosted TFS Team Project Collection https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection: Access Denied: Timothy Alex needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit collection-level information
I, 2016/08/22, 16:20:19.542, Failed to connect to the tfs project collection https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException: Failed to obtain the service account from the hosted TFS Team Project Collection https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection: Access Denied: Timothy Alex needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit collection-level information
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.AttemptToAddServiceAccountToGroup(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, TfsTeamProjectCollection server, TfsServiceAccount account, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.ChangeTfsRegistration(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
E, 2016/08/22, 16:20:19.551, Failed to obtain the service account from the hosted TFS Team Project Collection https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection: Access Denied: Timothy Alex needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit collection-level information
```

The log states that I need Edit collection-level information. I believe this is at the default collection level and I am afraid I will not get this persmission as this is something similar to super admin where I can have the power to delete/modify an existing project in the collection.

I believe this should not be provided to all the testers as this might lead to some accidental damages to the project.

Please correct me if I am wrong and advice as what I need to do next to make sure I am able to configure the test test controller successfully.

Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption regarding Edit collection-level information permission is wrong. It's not super admin. Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx carefully.

Just ask your TFS admin

- to add your account to project collection's Project Collection Test Service Accounts group or
- to tell you an existing service account used for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the info. TFS Admin added my account to Project Collection Test Service Accounts group. But still getting the same error.

Comment: I just checked, that Project Collection Test Service Accounts group doesn't have Edit collection-level information permission by default. But as you understand Edit collection-level information permission is not as super admin, could you ask TFS admin grant Edit collection-level information permission to your account explicitly? Generally speaking, test controller (or lab management later) must have some write permission in order to work correctly. Don't be afraid to ask such permissions if you follow official test controller/lab management instructions.